# Android app with Azure server: how to refresh local data automatically when server data changes?

Tags: android, azure

I'm trying to move an android app project from Firebase to Azure, and I've been working through the simple ToDo app tutorial on the Azure website:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-android-get-started-offline-data/

I've been using this tutorial to try to understand the basic techniques involved in retrieving data from an Azure SQL server.

As it stands, the sample app refreshes local data when the user clicks a 'refresh button', by using:

```
mToDoTable.pull(null).get();
```

(Where mToDoTable is a MobileServiceSyncTable.)

I want to change the app so that local data is refreshed automatically whenever server data changes: the user shouldn't need to click a refresh button.

I'd expected this to be straightforward, and that it would probably involve attaching a listener of some sort to mToDoTable.(It works in this kind of way in Firebase, and it's easy to do.)

My problem is that I can't find any guidance on how to do this in Azure: I haven't found anything in the tutorials, the documentation, or via extensive Google searching. This leads to me to think that I'm missing something obvious (not unlikely since I'm completely new to Azure, I have no SQL experience, and I'm fairly new to Android in general). Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the answer like "no, there is no built-in mechanism" or "yes, there is a callback function or a trigger that will do what you want", and when i implemented some project in a recent past, i could not find such out-of-the-box solution. Pretty sure that there is no mechanism, however.

What i did in our project was to poll the backend using [Exponential Back-off](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff) and event-driven approach (if-user-opens-then-poll-the-backend).

There are a lot of tutorials how to do that like [that](https://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2013/02/19/calculating-an-exponential-back-off-delay-based-on-failed-attempts/).